# MSVC treatment of ##__VA_ARGS__ vs. other compilers

Tags: c++, preprocessor

As an extension to the standard, the `##` preprocessor operator can be used to "eat" a trailing comma for `__VA_ARGS__`. This is supported in all my compilers of interest (GCC, clang, MSVC).

However, their handling of it is not the same. In particular, MSVC breaks in a way I don't understand (example below).
How can I write the `MYLOG` macro so that it works in all platforms?

Example program ([live link](https://godbolt.org/z/4615ox))

```
#include<cstdio>

#define LOG_HELPER(...)    printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#define MYLOG(fmt, ...)    LOG_HELPER("mylog: " fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define MYPRINTF(fmt, ...) printf(   "printf: " fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)

int main() {

    // Works in all cases I care about (GCC, clang, MSVC)
    MYPRINTF("foo\n");

    // Works in GCC+clang, but not MSVC!
    MYLOG("foo\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The error MSVC gives is: `error C2059: syntax error: ')'`

Indeed, looking at the processed output, the `MYLOG` line expands to:

```
printf("foo\n", )  // <- Note trailing comma - bad!
```

Is there a semi-clean way to get this to work in all cases?

**Note:** My main desire here is to get this to work in a cross-platform way. I realize `##` is non-standard, but I'm more interested in "works on MSVC+GCC+clang" than I am with strict standards compliance.

Also: I am aware of `__VA_OPT__` coming in C++20, but it is not an option for me right now.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: yes, in fact I wrote that question, long ago (:  I am trying to avoid argument-counting shenanigans, which is why I'm trying to make use of `##`.

Comment: Oups, I didn't see it was you who wrote that. I just remember having seen that when trying you some macro stuff myself. :-) Deleting comment...

Answer (score 1):

The easy way would be to have different definitions based on detected compiler. And note that MSVC (at least prior to the /Zc:preprocessor switch) will eat a trailing comma if **VA_ARGS** is empty.

```
#define LOG_HELPER(...)    printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#define MYLOG(fmt, ...)    LOG_HELPER("mylog: " fmt, __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define MYLOG(fmt, ...)    LOG_HELPER("mylog: " fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

Comment: I pasted your MSVC version into the godbolt link, and got the same compiler error. I even specified "/Zc:preprocessor-" to force it to use the old preprocessor. The `MYPRINTF` macro works without the `##` though, so I suspect the issue here has to do with chaining macros.

Answer (score 1):

I found an approach that works okay for my purposes:

```
#define MYLOG(...)    LOG_HELPER("mylog: " __VA_ARGS__)
```

It is, sadly, a bit specific to this particular usage (combining string literals).

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but simply changing your `LOG_HELPER()` macro to the following seems to make it work on all platforms you care about:

`#define LOG_HELPER(fmt, ...)    printf(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)`

[Working example](https://godbolt.org/z/534ex18Yn)

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but there doesn't seem to be an accepted answer, so here is another option.

If you add another, ignored, leading parameter to the `LOG_HELPER` macro's parameter list, the rest of the parameters get properly expanded by all compilers (even on ancient versions, see godbolt), including MSVC's traditional and new preprocessors.

By editing your example: ([godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/G4fr56Wd7))

```cpp
#include<cstdio>

#define LOG_HELPER(ignored, ...)    printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#define MYLOG(fmt, ...)    LOG_HELPER(IGNORED, "mylog: " fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define MYPRINTF(fmt, ...) printf(   "printf: " fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)


int main() {

    // Works in all cases I care about (GCC, clang, MSVC)
    MYPRINTF("foo\n");

    // Works in GCC+clang, ~~but not~~ AND MSVC!
    MYLOG("foo\n");       // printf("mylog: " "foo\n");
    MYLOG("foo %d\n", 1); // printf("mylog: " "foo %d\n",1);
    

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `...` is not allowed to map against 0 parameters.
Note: This may have been fixed in the standard now (not sure) but not all compilers have caught up.

```
MYLOG("foo\n");  // Here the expansion of ... maps to zero parameters.
```

The easy way to get around this is to add another layer and an artificial parameter you ignore to the end.

```
#define LOG_HELPER_INDIRECT(fmt, ...) LOG_HELPER("mylog: " fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define MYLOG(...)                    LOG_HELPER_INDIRECT(__VA_ARGS__, 1)
```

This way the `...` always maps to at least one parameter.
You just have to make sure that one parameter is ignored which in this case it will be,

Comment: Hmm... I don't like that you have to pay a runtime cost (passing an extra, unused argument), but it's an interesting approach, thanks.